# Trouble displaying converted .stl file in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

I imported the .stl file available here: https://www.thingiverse.com/download:3044581 into the default "Game" template in XCode. Converted to .scn. Dragged the file into the "ship.scn" scene there and resized it to about the size of the ship in the SceneKit editor by adjusting the Scale values.

No matter what I do, I can't get this model to display. I'm wondering if it's something about the model itself or the conversion process. Any ideas?

Very new to development! Would appreciate any and all help. I'd like to display this, or any, model, head-on, at launch and eventually rotate the model in place using accelerometer data.